# Weird error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function has no method 'split'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let me preface this by saying I am pretty much a JavaScript noob. I am currently back porting a jQuery 1.7 compatible script to jQuery 1.5 because we can't use 1.7 (because of legacy code I have no control over and will never be updated). The function I am having problems with is this (comes from Bootstrap 3):

```
function clearMenus() {
    $(backdrop).remove()
    $(toggle).each(function(e) {
        var $parent = getParent($(this))
        if (!$parent.hasClass('open'))
            return
        $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown'))
        if (e.isDefaultPrevented())
            return
        $parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown')
    })
}
```

I am getting the error that the object function does not have split method. I understand that there is no split method for objects (it is a function used on strings). What I don't understand is why a split method is being called as there is no split method being called (as far as I can tell).

What am I obviously missing and how do I address it?

Comment: Try using a Javascript debugger to find out where and on which value the `.split()` is actually being called within Bootstrap/jQuery? You're probably passing the wrong kind of parameter somewhere. The debugger should let you break on an exception, including a `TypeError`.

Comment: my only guess would be the use of this on your each() fx

Comment: Also, you might be able to use two versions of jQuery side-by-side with `.noConflict()`. Might be a better way forward than trying to make Bootstrap 3 compatible with an antiquated version of jQuery.

Comment: My guess is that `.trigger()` or `$.Event()` use split on `.` for name space.

Comment: @A.Wolff That's perfectly normal syntax inherited from C. I doubt it causes a problem here.

Comment: Add break point, walk through the code, see where the error is being fired. Have fun rewriting bootstrap, you are better off with noConflict.

Comment: @millimoose I tried that approach as well and it seemed to cause a conflict with another script dispite the fact it isn't suppose to. I aliased jQuery-1.8.1 to $jq181 and did a replace all "jQuery" in bootstrap 3 with $jq181. Didn't work. Did I do that wrong?

Comment: @user5013 I couldn't tell from just your description really. It was just a general idea, it's entirely possible it's not feasible because of some more obscure dependency somewhere.